# Xbox X/S controller on PS3?

Tags: ps3, controllers, xbox

I'm wondering if there's a way to use Xbox Series X/S controller on PlayStation 3? It doesn't matter if they're wired or wireless; is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible via external tools, but the solution depends on what kind of firmware do you have.

### Custom Firmware (CFW)

If you are using a console with custom firmware, you can use this plugin called [PS3xPAD](https://www.psx-place.com/resources/ps3xpad.22/), It allows you to remap any HID compatible gamepad like the Xbox One/Series X|S controller.

### Stock Console or Homebrew Enabler (HEN)

You will need to buy a 3rd party dongle that converts your Xbox One/Series X|S controller to a DualShock 3. One sunch example is the [CronusMax](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013E2KD5M).

This device makes your Xbox One/Series X|S controller show up as a regular DualShock 3 for the console, so it works without too much trouble. The way to configure them depends on the manufacturer, so remember to read the manual of the one you get.